# I can't transform NSData to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json

I want to get weather info:

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.weather.com.cn/adat/sk/101190403.html")
let data = NSData.init(contentsOfURL:url!)
var str = NSString(data:data!,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

If I use `print(str)`, it can show me the Chinese and the encoding is UTF8
but if I use `if print(data)`, it is like this:

```
Optional({"weatherinfo":{"city":"张家港","cityid":"101190403","temp":"11","WD":"西北风","WS":"2级","SD":"92%","WSE":"2","time":"10:25","isRadar":"0","Radar":"","njd":"暂无实况","qy":"1007"}})
```

Then search from here:

```
do {
    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
    print(jsonResult)
    } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
    }}
```

How can I turn the NSData to NSDictionary and show me the Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result is a JSON model based, you can use a library like JSONModel: https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel to parse and fill your class model:

```
{
   "weatherinfo":{
      "city":"寮犲娓�",
      "cityid":"101190403",
      "temp":"11",
      "WD":"瑗垮寳椋�",
      "WS":"2绾�",
      "SD":"92%",
      "WSE":"2",
      "time":"10:25",
      "isRadar":"0",
      "Radar":"",
      "njd":"鏆傛棤瀹炲喌",
      "qy":"1007"
   }
}
```

Next you can convert it to NSDictionary using it's method:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [weatherResult toDictionary];
```

Comment: oh! thanks! I feel so so excited because your helping .and my english is so bad..